# Implementing a dynamic UI factory in FP using map (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, factory

Would this qualify as performing a factory but in a FP way ?

Simply mapping a function that can take inputs for the element and returning an element along with its event handlers, this is dumbed down for the example.

```
const pageElements = ['input', 'radio', 'input']

const InputObj = () => {
    return 'Im a Input'
}

const RadioObj = () => {
    return 'Im a Radio'
}

const elementMap: Record<string, string> = ({
    input: InputObj(),
    radio: RadioObj()
})

const processPage = (pageElements: string[]) => {
    return pageElements.map(elementName => elementMap[elementName])
}

console.log(processPage(pageElements))
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the relevant programming language, whatever it might be.

Comment: @molbdnilo looks like Typescript. I added the tag, OP can change if necessary.

Comment: It is Typescript, ill update the question title too

Comment: This seems...overly-convoluted. I would just have a mapping between a name and a constructor function (class or plain function) so that you can dynamically call them, if you even need to: `{ input: makeInput, radio: makeRadio }`. That being said, usually when I see someone asking for this it's so they can declaratively write markup in JSON or something like that. Tread *extremely* carefully, the road of history is littered with the skulls of people who said "how hard can it be?"

Comment: So you are converting the inbound string directly to the relevant constructor (eval() ?) JSON defines the markup, probably going to be my 6th attempt in 2 years. Indeed many failed bowls of spaghetti left for dead.

Comment: @Marci no you don't use eval, you just map string names to the functions in an object `const mapFun = { a: somefun, b: someOtherFun };` and then you can call the functions dynamically using the strings 'a' and 'b': `mapFun['a']();` and yes, defining markup in a simpler data format is hard: you really don't want to couple the shape of your UI to the shape of your data.